# oauth2 strategy with ruby on rails with many clients that have an API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

I have been researching oauth2 for a while now and haven't come up with the perfect solution and wanted to see if anyone else has done this before. Currently I have two applications inside of one code base. The only thing these applications share is authentication. What I am looking to do is to create a third application for the oauth2 server. Then I want to separate the existing applications into two applications. Trying to follow how Google handles their oauth stuff. So the domains would be something like this.

- http://accounts.domain.com
- http://app1.domain.com
- http://app2.domain.com

I found some good information in these two posts about doorkeeper and devise. Currently I am using devise so that makes that part easier.

- https://dev.mikamai.com/2015/02/11/oauth2-on-rails/
- https://dev.mikamai.com/2015/03/02/oauth2-on-rails-the-client-application/

So each of these applications app1 and app2 will have API's that the use will need to be authenticated against.

So I have the following questions.

1. If app1 needs to validate with accounts sub domain does that mean from an API perspective I need to call the oauth2 server application on each request? That seems like a lot of overhead. Is this the way that Google does it or do they have some trick?
2. Would app1 and app2 each be responsible for their own session timeout? What happens if app1 session is valid but the user deleted their accounts directly by going to the auth2 server application?
3. If app1 and app2 are responsible for session then would they also want to call back to accounts oauth2 server to validate the user still exists?

I'm trying to flush all of this out and haven't found a good example of how this would work when the oauth clients are actually API's plus they are web apps too. Maybe I am over thinking it too and that making the extra call for each API request is the way.

Any help or tutorial on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-8) provides five grant techniques:

- Authorization code grant
- Implicit grant
- Resource owner credentials grant
- Client credentials grant
- Refresh token grant

I believe our discussion is about `Client credentials grant` (I think google uses it generally).

Let's try to understand this flow chart:
[image]

So, [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-11) in the step `[E]`:

> Steps (C) and (D) repeat until the access token expires.  If the
> client knows the access token expired, it skips to step (G);
> otherwise, it makes another protected resource request.

It means it actually does not hits `Authorization Server` on each request. It only hits authorization server when `client` found that token is expired. So, if our deletes itself, it makes the token expired!

Maybe these document could help you more:

1. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749
2. https://alexbilbie.com/guide-to-oauth-2-grants/

Cheers!